# Ag Grid - Treelist Filter - Remember state

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm currently using a treelist to display data to filter
[image]

Everytime when there is a new list of data populated while I'm opening the filter, the treelist will get collapse

Is there any setting/solution that I can use so that the treelist will remember the expand/collapse state everytime the data get refresh?